# Optional for Post request jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, resttemplate

I'm building a rest client in java. I have the following object Mode.

```
 public class Mode {

 @JsonProperty("Replicated")
 private Optional<Replicated> replicated = Optional.empty();

 @JsonProperty("Global")
 private Optional<Global> global = Optional.empty();

 public Optional<Global> getGlobal() {
    return global;
 }

 public Optional<Replicated> getReplicated() {
    return replicated;
 }

 public void setGlobal(Global global) {
    this.global = Optional.ofNullable(global);
 }

 public void setReplicated(Replicated replicated) {
    this.replicated = Optional.ofNullable(replicated);
 }
}
```

The 2 fields are Optionals.

This approach works for the GET request. But my issue happens for the POST request. In fact my object sent is the following :

```
 { Mode : {Replicated : {present : true} ...
```

So my workaround is the following :

```
@JsonProperty("Global")
public Global getGlobalForPost() {
    if (global.isPresent()) {
        return global.get();
    }
    return null;
}

@JsonProperty("Replicated")
public Replicated getReplicatedForPost() {
    if (replicated.isPresent()) {
        return replicated.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do you know a better solution, Maybe something in jackson which do the trick?

Comment: Yes: don't use Optionals for your fields, and use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datatypes to support Optionals.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson you cannot make the difference between optional and non-optional fields. Just declare any field in your POJO. If a field is not present in your JSON structure then Jackson will not call the setter. You may keep track of wether a setter has been called with a flag in the POJO.